# Find centroid in a pixels cluster

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, centroid

**How do I calculate the centroid of a cluster formed by pixels?**

I'm representing the pixels by their RED, BLUE and GREEN values (for example, `pixel(116 133 55)`).

The centroid should be *the mean of instances in the cluster*, but **how can I calculate the mean between pixels**?

[I tried to calculate the mean on each color (centroid["RED"]=sum_red_pixel_values/number of pixels and so on) but **it gives wrong results**]

If it helps in any way, I'm using Euclidean distance function.

Comment: How do you know the result is wrong?

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I defined the centroids this way and used K-Means to segment an image. After the reassignment of the centroids the clusters go insane.

Comment: Using the average of each component (i.e. color) is the correct way to do it. It's hard to tell what is the problem with you algorithm without any code or details, but that logic shouldn't be it.

Comment: Sum of red / N will give the centroid red channel, no two ways about it. You must somehow be summing the wrong pixels for the cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum_red_pixel_values/number of pixels` will give you the average red intensity. If you want the centroid you need to find the average x and y position of all the pixels weighted by pixel intensity.

```
centroid.x = sum(pixel.red * pixel.x) / sum(pixel.red)
centroid.y = sum(pixel.red * pixel.y) / sum(pixel.red)
```

where sum is over all pixels.

You could compute this separately for red green and blue and then average, but if you just want the average it would be more efficient to average (possibly a weighted average if you want luminosity) the red green and blue channels for each pixel first and *then* compute the centroid based on that.